# Why does Pakistan continue to use F-16s?

Tags: military, fighter, f-16, pakistan

Why does Pakistan continue to use F-16s even though they have their own JF-17s?

What features do Pakistani F-16s have which their JF-17s don't?

Comment: Because they're really expensive machines that still run well and are still highly capable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The airframe of JF-17 is a lot less advanced than F-16(A), even though the electronics are a lot more contemporary.

1. Payload and Empty weight:

   [JF-17 has an empty weight of 14520lb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAC/PAC_JF-17_Thunder) while [F-16A is 15600lb](https://fas.org/man/dod-101/sys/ac/f-16.htm). However the maximum takeoff weight are 27999lb and 37500lb respectively. This means the mission consumables (fuel + armament) of JF-17 is only 60% of F-16A(13479lb vs 21900lb).
2. Powerplant

   JF-17 is powered by [RD-33/93](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Klimov_RD-33) engine with thrust of 18285lb while F-16 is 27000lb. Again JF-17's thrust is only 2/3 of F16.
3. Fly-by-wire

   To reduce cost JF-17 is only equipped with digital fly-by-wire (FBW) system in the pitch axis but F-16 has FBW on all three. This, together higher thrust, makes F-16 are more agile fighter.

JF-17 by design is a lighter and cheaper fighter than F-16, so it inherently has a relatively smaller range and payload capacity, which is unfortunately worsened by its excessive structural weight. Had PAF not maintained a number of heavier and more capable fighters, these short comings of JF-17 could be exploited to catastrophic levels by their potential enemies equipped with much more capable heavyweight SU-30s.

Apparently F-16s in PAF are showing their age and PAF has been seeking for replacements for a while, e.g. [Chengdu J-10/FC-20](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chengdu_J-10) and [Shenyang J-31/FC-31](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shenyang_FC-31). However (IMO) due to PAF's tight budget neither are making any meaningful progress as of right now and the combo of JF-17 and F-16 seems sufficiently effective for the current status of geopolitics.